# Is it possible that a python def contains both "yield" and "return"?

Tags: python, tornado

Currently I am learning the python tornado, and I find an interesting def [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html), the sample code goes as

```
@gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    return response.bodyere
```

As you see the def function contains both yield and return... So, is it follow the python rules ? How can we use this kind of def ? anyone give me some samples will be very appreciate...

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I imagine this is for python >= 3.3

Comment: I tried, it always gives me the exception 'return' with argument inside generator

Comment: @liuzhidong as I said in my comment that syntax is only valid for python >= 3.3

Comment: Thanks, only valid for >= 3.3, got it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def f():
...     yield 1
...     return 2
... 
>>> g = f()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: 2
```

`return` in a generator stops its execution and ends the iteration by raising a `StopIteration`. Apparently, giving a value in `return` just passes it as an argument to the `StopIteration` exception.

It was [pointed out](/questions/27089289/is-it-possible-that-a-python-def-contains-both-yield-and-return/27089375#comment-42685903) in the comments that passing a value like this is only allowed since Python 3.3.

This value can't be seen in normal iteration (i.e. `for x in f()`).

It seems like Tornado does something special with it, by iterating using `next` and catching that exception. Coroutines are a complex topic. This could be the "result" of the coroutine, and the `yield`s in it would be just to suspend execution and exchange data.

Answer (score 2):

Not in Python 2. In Python 2, a function that contains "yield" can have a bare "return" with no value, but it is not allowed to return a value. Tornado has a solution to this: you can yield and then raise gen.Return(value):

```
@gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    raise gen.Return(response.body)
```

In Python 3.3 and later, a function that contains "yield" can also return a value:

```
@gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    return response.body
```

Python 3.3 gained the ability to return a value from a generator in [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380), along with the new statement "yield from".